# C++ convert int array to int16_t array

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I convert an int array to int16_t array in C++ or C with low cost? Assume that all the values in int array are within the range of int16_t.

I know two options:

i. Use for loop to assign each element in the int array to corresponding element in int16_t array.

```
int *a = new int[2];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;

int16_t *b = new int16_t[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   b[i] = a[i];
}
```

But it needs to do copy and has overhead.

ii. Use cast

```
int16_t* c = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(a);

//1 0 2 0
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cout << (int)r[i] << endl;
}
```

But I do not want those 0.

Is there any other low-cost way to transfer int array[2] to int16_t array[2] and keep the values?

Comment: There's a high chance on modern architectures that you're going to be truncating values. An `int` is 32-bits or 64-bits anymore (not guaranteed, but  generally so) and an `int16_t` is guaranteed to be 16-bits. Reinterpreting the pointer isn't going to be what you want since you're essentially turning an `int` into **two** `int16_t`'s, assuming that an `int` is 32-bits on your system.

Comment: Also, since your carving up ints, you may get surprising results on big endian architectures in the second, reinterpret_cast example

Comment: Yes. But I receive the int array from other components, though I know that the values are guaranteed to be within the range of 16-bits integer (int16_t). So a[i] will not be truncated, if I do b[i] = (int16_t) a[i].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot make any assumptions about the size of `int` (the standard does **not** give any statement about the **exact** size of the primitive data types) you can't do any fancy tricks using casts here. Your example:

```
int16_t* c = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(a);
```

does not work because on **your** system the type `int` happens to be **32 bit** long, so for each `int` you will get **two** `int16_t`. In your case, it so happens that all values are in a certain range, so the second `int16_t` is always 0.

---

I would suggest just copying your integers. Anything else is premature optimization.

Comment: This is the absolute correct answer. Beat me to it.

Comment: I know that the values are guaranteed to be within the range of 16-bits integer (int16_t or I can use short as well), though they are stored as 32-bits int. Copying has overhead while my component requires high efficiency.

Comment: There is simply no way to reinterpret the data if the memory layout is not matching. So there is nothing you can do besides copying. Do not optimize before measuring! That is premature optimization.

Comment: The standard does specify that an int MUST be at least 16 bits. Per definition of INT_MIN.

Comment: That does not matter in this case, though. Here, an exact guarantuee is needed that is obviously not given.

Comment: The statement is incorrect "that you cannot make any assumptions about the size of an int. The standard does not..." You can see by my answer that i agree that a copy operation must be performed. While a portable solution like the second is possible with a conditional value used to increment the index computed from the size difference of int16_t and int. Assuming as the OP does the values are prequalified to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Because your target int16_t is represented by fewer bits than your source int (32-bits or more) the bits must be transformed from 32/64 bits to 16 bits. Your first solution is  correct, but compilers will warn on the assignment to a smaller int. A static_cast to int16_t on the right side of the assignment will silence the warning.

Yes, by transform I mean copy.

Answer (score -1):

Can you simply avoid the copy and just use an `int1_t6` array?

As you are increasing the size of the array elements (maybe, depends what platform), you'd either have to copy, or use a helper function/cast on each access. As the values are still smaller, you do not gain anything having them as an `int16_t` unless you need to modify the values with other `int16_t`'s.

I guess it really depends on what you need to do with the values once they are an `int16_t`.

```
int16_t getArrVal( const unsigned index ){
 return array[index];
}
```